# par() function acting up in Rstudio - plotting weird results or no results at all

Tags: r, rstudio

I've found a couple of similar posts but unfortunately not one reply seems to fix my problem.

Data = working on the [uscrime](http://www.statsci.org/data/general/uscrime.html) dataset.

Essentially, I'm having trouble my plots when using par() in RStudio. It's not the first time it happens that all of the sudden after re-rerunning a chunk in R, the plot is no longer displayed inline nor in the Plots window.

My code is the following:

```
par(mfrow=c(3,5))
for(i in colnames(crime[,1:15])){
  plot(crime[,i],crime[,16], main=print(paste("Crime vs", i)), xlab=i, ylab="Crime")
  lines(lowess(crime[,i],crime[,16]), col="red")
  abline(lm(crime[,16]~crime[,i]), col="blue")
}
```

The first time I ran the chunk the plots showed up:

[image: Here are my plots (apologize but I can't post pictures yet)]

Now, as soon as I tried to plot something different (same data but with a transformed column) using the same approach, nothing appeared inline. Here's my code:

```
par(mfrow=c(3,5))
for(i in colnames(crime2[,1:15])){
  plot(crime2[,i],crime2[,16], main=print(paste("Crime vs", i)), xlab=i, ylab="Crime")
  lines(lowess(crime2[,i],crime2[,16]), col="red")
  abline(lm(crime2[,16]~crime2[,i]), col="blue")
}
```

I tried restarting R and running everything again and ow I'm getting a weird result where some of the information I passed to my first par() call is getting displayed in my charts (see how I have two blue curves when I should have a blue and a red one).

[image: Second output]

Now, I've been reading about 'devices' and plots but since I'm an R noob I can't figure out what's wrong on my own. It looks like I have to call dev.off() at some point but I don't quite get it. My expectation is that there's something wrong (or an additional step to take) with my par() calls but I haven't found the replies in R Documentation.

Here's a view of my Markdown config

[image: img]

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for the effort providing your code, but this look like a markdown issue. Can you provide a bigger view of the document and how you created chunks ?

Comment: Thanks @Gowachin! I just edited the post adding a screenshot of my Markdown settings. Is that what you were after? Let me know what you need and will provide it!

Comment: It would be helpful if you put together a complete document that illustrates the issue.  Start with your real document, and delete everything except this code chunk and enough of the header to still show the problem.